# Torque signal fft

Tags: matlab, fft, fourier-transform, noise, sampling

I have the following torque signal picked up with a 10.240Hz sampling rate from a testbench.

[image: signal over time and its fft]

I am studying its fft which I create on Octave with the following code:

```
ftpar=fft(torque);

nfft=length(ftpar); 

freqtpar=abs(ftpar)/nfft;

freqt2par=freqtpar(1:nfft/2); 

mediapar=freqt2par(1); 

freqt2par=2*freqt2par(2:end); 

deltafreq=Fs/nfft; 

xfft=[deltafreq:deltafreq:(Fs/2-Fs/nfft)];

plot (xfft.',freqt2par);
```

When looking at the 10 frequencies with the biggest amplitudes the one at the lowest frequency is at 24 Hz all of the others are at higher frequencies. However, by looking at the time domain graph there seems to be a big oscillation with around a 0.5 Hz frequency.

Where is that oscillation coming from? Am I missing something when doing the fft? The lowest frequency I get from the fft is 0.08 Hz so I should be seeing that kind of frecuency.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The units in the FFT plot are incorrect. Since Fourier transform coefficients are time integrals, the units are those of $\text{amplitude} \cdot \text{time}$, or, in your case $\text{Nm}\cdot\text{s}$.

Comment: You also didn't provide a zoomed-in plot of the lower frequencies, so it's impossible to see what you're missing there *and* usually you want the FFT plot to have logarithmic vertical scale. You probably should look at the [`plotfft`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/ltfat/function/plotfft.html) function.